# PHP not throwing exceptions when MariaDB times out query

Tags: php, mariadb

PHP doesn't seem to throw an exception when MariaDB times out a query. Instead it just returns an empty result set.
We tried running this via PHP PDO:

```
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time = 2 FOR
SELECT "A", SLEEP(10);
```

I'd expect it to throw some sort of PDOException, like when you do something similar in Postgres, but instead it completes successfully and returns an empty result set. There doesn't seem to be any way to distinguish between a timed out query and one that just doesn't return anything.

Anyone know of any way to get this to throw an exception?

Comment: Maybe show your PHP code so we don't have to make a blind guess as to what you're doing wrong.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as I'm interested by the answer… Thanks

Comment: We're finding this issue too and think it might be due to max_statement_time being a MariaDB setting and we're using the mysql driver for PDO. This means the driver doesn't recognise the error code given back and just fails silently. With other drivers, specifically built for MariaDB it seems to work (eg within phpstorm). Would have thought it would throw a general error though...

Answer (score 0):

Before you connect to the database, be sure to enable query error reporting using:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Visit the PHP Documentation of [mysqli_report](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) for more details.

Also calling a query using **$result_mode** *MYSQLI_USE_RESULT* doesn't throw an exception for me either. Be sure to use *MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT* instead.
Default **$result_mode** is *MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT*.

Visit the PHP Documentation of [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more details.